# How to add a parameter store key as a sub list

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-boot, yaml, properties-file, aws-parameter-store

I have YAML file and need to add it as parameter store in aws cloud as follows

```
foo_bar:
  - dummy_key1: 1
    dummy_key2: 2
```

I have added it as a parameter key name:

```
foo_bar[0].dummy_key1
foo_bar[0].dummy_key2
```

but it results in this message

> Only a mix of letters, numbers and the following 3 symbols .-_ are
>   allowed.

on aws

how can I represent this YAML file as a key in parameter store?